# combining multiple images to one on html5 canvas

Tags: image, html5-canvas

How to combine multiple images together on html5 canvas and then display them as a single image?

Please help.

Comment: I am having the similar problem at the moment. I know a bit about html5 canvas and don't think it is the key problem in my case. What I concern is that how to position and compact the images which have different dimensions.

Answer (score 7):

To draw multiple Image on canvas use the following code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_id');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var imageObj1 = new Image();
  imageObj1.src = "your image source"
  imageObj1.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj1, x, y);
  };

var imageObj2 = new Image();
  imageObj2.src = "your image source"
  imageObj2.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj2, x, y);
  };
```

Now Get Image Data URL from canvas

```
  // get png data url
  var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

 // get jpeg data url 
 var jpegUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

If you want **ImageData** then  use

```
context.getImageData(x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: This just helped me, awesome! Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting undefined for Image, x, y, width, and height and I don't see you defining it here. 

Where is it defined?