# Compile two photos into one

Tags: javascript

I want complie two photos into one in javascript is there any code do that (it is not in the same domain)

so, the first image is the original and the second will be a logo

Comment: WHY duplicate? that question is totally different

Comment: Add more details to your question, i.e. how do you want to combine / compile ? them...

Comment: I mean the first image is the original and the second is a logo

Comment: Then this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742381/combining-multiple-images-to-one-on-html5-canvas might be of help

Comment: @le_m thank you. but I want it without canvas .

Comment: you can either overlay two (absolutely positioned) HTML image elements or create an (off-screen) canvas element and compose a new image on that (which you can then set as the source of another HTML image element).

Comment: @le_m I don't want to use any html, I just want to do it with javascript

Comment: Then - given your photos are given as either a base64 string, a binary string or an array buffer - you need to decode the image format (such as JPEG, PNG or BMP), merge the color channels e.g. by multiplication and encode again into your desired output format. There might be libraries available for that which bring their own en- and decoder.

Comment: @le_m thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the dataUri version of your canvas :

```
canvas.toDataURL();
```

More infos [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). But be careful of the output size.

Comment: Won't work if the images are cross-domain.

Comment: I want to compile the photos first